# How to compress JS and css in java at build time using maven-minify-plugin with YUI compressor 

Tags: java, javascript, maven-2, yui, minify

I want to use **maven-minify** plugin with YUI compressor for compressing JS and css at build time. 
My JS and CSS are kept in different folders. For instance. 'X' JS files are present in one folder and remaining are present in different folder. Same is the case with CSS files.

Also I want to know, how does reference of JS and CSS gets changed in JSP,if in case the file name changes from **jsFileName.js** to something like **jsFileName-min.js**

Please let me know how to use this plugin as I am completely new to this.

Answer (score 16):

Use [Samaxes plug-in](http://code.google.com/p/maven-samaxes-plugin/), configure like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-minify-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>min-js</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <cssSourceDir>relative/path/to/css/dir</cssSourceDir>
                <cssSourceFiles>
                    <cssSourceFile>subfolder1/1.css</cssSourceFile>
                    <cssSourceFile>subfolder1/3.css</cssSourceFile>
                    <cssSourceFile>subfolder2/2.css</cssSourceFile>
                </cssSourceFiles>
                <cssTargetDir>relative/path/to/final/location</cssTargetDir>
                <cssFinalFile>minified.css</cssFinalFile>

                <jsSourceDir>relative/path/to/js/dir</jsSourceDir>
                <jsSourceFiles>
                    <jsSourceFile>subfolder3/1.js</jsSourceFile>
                    <jsSourceFile>subfolder4/2.js</jsSourceFile>
                </jsSourceFiles>
                <jsFinalFile>minifiedname.js</jsFinalFile>
                <jsTargetDir>rel/path/to/final/location</jsTargetDir>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>minify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <!-- more execution statements -->
    </executions>                               
</plugin>
```

Comment: I am trying to use your solution but I am getting the error "plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" in my pom.xml. I am using Eclipse Indigo. Any thoughts?

Comment: cnage phase to compile or package `<phase>package</phase>`

Comment: @bhuvan If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as answered by clicking on the up-tick next to this answer. [See here how](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If you liked the answer, you may also up-vote by clicking on up arrow next to the answer.